# Is $\mathbb{R}^{d_1}\times (0,\infty)^{d_2}$ a $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-locally uniform domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, sobolev-spaces, besov-space

Is $\mathbb{R}^{d_1}\times (0,\infty)^{d_2}$ a $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-locally uniform domain, for integer $d_1 \geq 0, d_2 \geq 0$? I am trying to get a grasp on these domains and am having a hard time proving this.

The definition:

> A domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-locally uniform for $\varepsilon, \delta>0$ if any $x,y \in \Omega$ with $\| x-y \| \leq \delta$ can be joined by a rectifiable arc $\gamma \subset \Omega$ satisfying for any point $z \in \gamma$
>
> 1. $l(\gamma) \leq \varepsilon \| x-y \|$, and
> 2. $\min\{l(\gamma'), l(\gamma'')\} \leq \mathrm{dist}(z, \partial \Omega)$,
>
> where $l(\gamma)$ is the Euclidean length of the arc $\gamma$, and $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ are the two components of $\gamma\setminus \{z\}$. $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$.

My first instinct was that, for a simple domain like that, a line segment should work as said arc. Simple counter-example is, suppose $\Omega=(0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)$, and put $x=(x_0, \beta_0)$ and $y=(\beta_1, y_1)$ such that $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are arbitrarily small, the distance between $x$ and $y$ are lower than $\delta$, and $y_1=C x_0$ for a (very) large $C$. Then there is $z$ on the line segment between $x$ and $y$ that is closer to the boundary than to $x$ or $y$. I spent a while on this example and couldn't come up with an arc that would satisfy the second condition..

Comment: Should condition (1) be $l(\gamma) \leq (1+\varepsilon) \lVert x - y \rVert$? Otherwise unless I'm mistaken, it seems like you always need $\varepsilon \geq 1$; which is fine but then $\varepsilon$ seems like a strange choice of notation.

Comment: The definition is correct. I agree it's an unconventional use of $\varepsilon$, but it is standard in this context.

Comment: Doesn't making $y_1=Cx_0$ for large $C$ break the $\| x-y\|\leq \delta$ condition? Or are you making $C$ depend on $\delta$? As for curves satisfying 2. my first guess would be piecewise-linear ones, with slopes adapted to move away from the appropriate portion of the boundary as fast as possible (so for instance if $x$ is very close to the horizontal axis, move upward); do these not work?